# Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'SegmentFetcher' could not be found

Tags: react-native

randomly whenever a component reloads, I will get the following error: `Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'SegmentFetcher' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.` And if I reload, then it disappears, only to appear again later down the line. I have been unable to resolve this issue, and the other similar posts have been unable to provide me with any clarification. [Here is a screenshot of the error for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdANy.png).

Comment: Hi, did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @greenskin no, unfortunately I couldn't figure it out.